# How to get Profile details link for User from user profile in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app, napa

Currently I'm working on SharePoint online app, 
I'm able to get users from user profile in office 365 site.

Now I'm trying get the Profile details URL :

https://Akshay.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?u=f0b9ed1d-83fa-4c82-976d-027f02711a83&v=profiledetails

[image]

How can I get that URL for each user using SharePoint APP

Answer (score 1):

You need to the `UserUrl` property to get the Delve(old mysite) url. Try below code. It iterates through all user profiles and logs the user url in console:

```
//Get User Profile Property for Site Users 
function getUsersDetails(Success,Error) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 

    var users = web.get_siteUsers();
    clientContext.load(users);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
       var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
       var personsProperties = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < users.get_count();i++)
       {
           var user = users.getItemAtIndex(i);
           var personName = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(user.get_loginName(),'UserUrl');
           personsProperties.push(personName);
       }

       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
           function() {
             Success(personsProperties);
           },
           Error);

    },
    Error);
}

var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/';
$.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js', function () {
  $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.UserProfiles.js', function () {
    getUsersDetails(function(usersProperties){
       for(var i = 0; i < usersProperties.length;i++)
       {
           console.log(usersProperties[i].get_value());
       }
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to use REST API, the endpoint would be as below. You need to write your own iteration logic here :

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='UserUrl')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can use the following url
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?p=JohnDoe%40wortell.nl&v=work